# Hashicorp Vault Installation as part of Umbrella Helm Chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

We have an umbrella helm chart which has Vault as one of the services. Many services depend on vault for secrets to be injected before starting.
Problem is since helm does not have ordering all the pods starts off and they do not get the secrets injected.

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The pods usually keep trying until everything is in place - unless there is a restart policy

Comment: Is there a way to make vault come up first ?

Comment: Not that i am aware of